# Outlook, Webdav Calendars, and Internal DNS

Tags: outlook, internal-dns, webdav, outlook-2010, calendar

I wish I knew a better way to title this problem, so if anyone can think of a more appropriate title, please let me know.  I've been banging my head on this problem for a little while, and usually I just work around it, but I felt it was time to ask for some help to get it solved.

**Background**

On our network, we keep a Webdav server which is located at `intranet:8080` (`10.0.0.2:8080`).  On this server our employees publish their Outlook calendars using the Share to Internet feature in Outlook.  Within this folder is also a PHP file named `index.php` that lists off the calendars based off the employees names and provides `webcal://` links (in the form of `webcal://intranet:8080/Firstname_Lastname_calendar.ics`) to the calendars to facilitate employees subscribing to each other's calendars.

We also have an Active Directory server at `10.0.0.1`.  The Active Directory server also provides DHCP for our network (setting itself as the primary DNS server and `8.8.8.8` as the secondary).

**The Problem**

One some computers when they click the links on `intranet:8080` to subscribe to another employee's calendar they get an error message saying that Outlook *"Cannot verify or add calendar to Outlook."*

If I manually enter `webcal://intranet:8080/Firstname_Lastname_calendar.ics` (or even `http://intranet:8080/Firstname_Lastname_calendar.ics`) I receive the same error message.  However if I enter `webcal://10.0.0.2:8080/Firstname_Lastname_calendar.ics` I do not receive an error message and the calendar is subscribed to.

This to me would appear to be an issue with DNS, but doing an `nslookup` on intranet returns `10.0.0.2` as provided by `10.0.0.1`, and as we had previously seen, the web browser on the computer has had no issue accessing `http://intranet:8080/` either.

As I said earlier, the issue doesn't happen on every computer in our network, and I've not really been able to work out a pattern for where it happens either.  Any ideas?  It would be fantastic for these employees to be able to easily subscribe to calendars without the IT department's help.

Comment: On the computers with the issue, is it always?  If so, if you modify their hosts file with intranet pointing to 10.0.0.2, does it start to work everytime?  If so, yeah DNS.

Comment: On a computer experiencing the issue, what does the "Pinging ..." line look like? Is it a FQDN? If it has no dots and/or is all caps, that indicates a NetBIOS name and is likely the result of a WINS lookup.

Comment: Also, try accessing it via it's FQDN.

Comment: I'll give the FQDN a shot next time it crops up.  That is definitely a good idea.  Sorry that its been a bit for answering this, it hasn't come up again in a bit and I've not had a moment to go back to the computers it was showing up on (we just worked around it on them).

Comment: Problem was eventually made moot.  It went away when I rebuilt our domain later that year.  Our set up makes a whole lot more sense now and the issue has not surfaced since.